# Table with fixed header height and other rows a percentage of container

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table with fixed header height (f.ex. 20px) and other rows height should be defined by percentage of the container (f.ex. 12%).

Row number varies from 4 to 6 and that is the cause that my table behaves in a wrong way. Height of header changes depending on the number of rows, despite it being defined in the css (min-height, height and max-height to be sure).

Here's a sample CSS:

```
#container
{
  height: 800px;
}

#t1
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  //height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#head_row
{
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

tbody tr
{
    height: 12%;
    max-height: 12%;
    min-height: 12%;
}

tbody td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 12%;
    max-height: 12%;
    min-height: 12%; 
}
```

Here is a sample JSfiddle of what I'm trying to achieve, but without setting table height to 100% it doesn't work and I commented it out.

[**jsfiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnjm4/2/)

What did I forget or what am I doing wrong? Is there any way to do it using only HTML and CSS?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to make a small calendar (I didn't write it earlier) and I just looked up how google does this:

[**Google calendar**](https://www.google.com/calendar/)

They have header as one table and every row as a div with a one-row table inside it... 
Well, I believe that people at Google know what they're doing, but is there really no simplier way?

Comment: Percentage height is relative to the parent element, you need to "pass it along" to your destination element. So if you intend to have percentage height on the table's rows, you need to have a height set on the table too, an absolute height will work, and a percentage height will work, too (which is again relative to the table's container).

Comment: You're right, I understand the part about table height now, but the rows still remain.

Comment: If I'm thinking correctly I can't set manually row heights percentage correctly if table height is set to 100%? If I'll have 4 rows for example they'll always expand to the size of container? Fixed pixel height would propably work, but I don't know the desired height. It should depend on container height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your table height as follows.

```
    height: 100%.
```

Which will refer Container height as you have defined. (min-height :800px; for Container div is more conventional so that Container div can grow in case of more data).

```
    height: 800px;
```

If you remove Container height the table will shrink back to minimum required height.

Comment: But what about tbody and thead row size?

Comment: Let other css be as it is. just add `height: 100%` to table. I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. When height is 100% every row changes its height for the table to fill the remaining space. So instead of row having desired 12% height it's height is (container size-header size)/number of rows.

Comment: If you want to have rows exactly 12% height then add an empty row set at the end of table without height specified.

Comment: This solution is really 'dirty', but if I remove borders and don't let user select anything it magickaly works, so you'll get an accept from me. Thanks